# Is it possible to see the CPU % or time usage per "thread" when using Python's threading library

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Given the python application is taking 100% of a single core, I would like to determine how much of that 100% is being taking by each "thread" running within that Python application and print the results to console?

Is this possible?

Updated with example and output of initial suggestions:

```
import threading
def main(self):
for i in range(
    int(self.type1_thread_limit)
):  # start threads for pushing type1 API data to cache
    worker = threading.Thread(target=self.type1_worker, args=())
    worker.start()

for i in range(
    int(self.type2_thread_limit)
):  # start threads for pushing type2 API data to cache
    worker = threading.Thread(
        target=self.type2_worker, args=()
    )
    worker.start()

for i in range(
    int(self.type1_dbthread_limit)
):  # start threads for pushing type1 data from cache to DB
    worker2 = threading.Thread(target=self.type1_db_worker, args=())
    worker2.start()

for i in range(
    int(self.type2__dbthread_limit)
):  # start threads for pushing type2 data from cache to DB
    workerDepth = threading.Thread(
        target=self.type2_db_worker, args=()
    )
    workerDepth.start()

while True:
    #schedule work for threads.....
```

Here is the output when I run ps -T -p pid:

PID    SPID TTY          TIME CMD
68085   68085 ?        00:11:52 python3
68085   68146 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68147 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68148 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68149 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68150 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68151 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68152 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68154 ?        00:00:00 python3
68085   68698 ?        00:16:00 python3
68085   68699 ?        00:16:22 python3
68085   68700 ?        00:16:15 python3
68085   68701 ?        00:16:38 python3
68085   68702 ?        00:16:01 python3
68085   68703 ?        00:16:44 python3
68085   68704 ?        00:16:04 python3
68085   68705 ?        00:16:27 python3
68085   68706 ?        00:16:39 python3
68085   68707 ?        00:16:42 python3
68085   68708 ?        00:16:40 python3
68085   68709 ?        00:16:33 python3
68085   68710 ?        00:16:25 python3
68085   68711 ?        00:16:52 python3
68085   68712 ?        00:16:23 python3
68085   68713 ?        00:06:50 python3
68085   68714 ?        00:07:08 python3
68085   68715 ?        00:06:42 python3
68085   68716 ?        00:06:41 python3
68085   68717 ?        00:07:12 python3
68085   68718 ?        00:07:06 python3
68085   68719 ?        00:06:59 python3
68085   68720 ?        00:13:37 python3
68085   68721 ?        00:13:30 python3
68085   68722 ?        00:13:33 python3
68085   68723 ?        00:15:08 python3
68085   68724 ?        00:00:01 python3
68085   68725 ?        00:00:01 python3

Here is what I see for "threads" in VS Code Callstack when running python code in debug mode:

•   MainThread
•   APScheduler
•   Thread-7 (type1_worker)
•   Thread-8 (type1_worker)
•   Thread-9 (type2_worker)
•   Thread-10 (type2_worker)
•   Thread-11 (type1_db_worker)
•   Thread-12 (type1_db_worker)
•   Thread-13 (type2_db_worker)
•   Thread-14 (type2_db_worker)

Comment: Something like `ps -T -p <pid>` (`"-T"` option of the ps command enables thread views) ? `top`/`htop` has something similar too

Comment: do you have example code ?  otherwise the general response is "yes".

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I have updated the question with an example and additional details based on the comments.